# Simpler-wick contraction in node of tikz loop produces unwanted arrow head

Tags: tikz-pgf, simplewick

The following code produces an unwanted arrowhead on the Wick contraction symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{simpler-wick}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) to [scale=4,in=60,out=300,loop] node [right] {$\wick{ \c{a} \c{c} }$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I am working in the overleaf environment and the code above produces:

[image: Wick contraction on loop node with unwanted arrowhead]

What I want is something like this:

[image: Wick contraction on loop node without unwanted arrowhead]

I've minimized the working example as far as I could and still can't find why that arrowhead is showing up...

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @Qrrbrbirlbel --- that workaround is just what I was looking for! If you post as an answer I can accept! One question though: what do you mean by nesting TikZ pictures? What would be a recommend best practice in this example?

Comment: Good question. Depends on how many wick diagrams per TikZ picture you need. And how we can adjust the `\wick` internals to counteract possible bad settings (if there are even anymore) – unfortunately, that package doesn't provide a good interface to add these settings to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `simpler-wick` package uses TikZ internally.

The `loop` key sets the arrow tip specification `->` and also `shorten >` with some amount. Since you use this key with a `to` path operation instead of the `edge` operation both those settings don't show up in the `\draw` path but they will into the paths of the node.

A quick workaround would be to use

```
\wick[/tikz/-, /tikz/shorten >=+0pt]{ … }
```

If you use more than one `\wick` per TikZ picture, you can do

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[execute at begin node=\tikzset{-, shorten >=+0pt}]
\draw (0,0) to [scale=4, in=60, out=300, loop]
               node [right] {$\wick{ \c{a} \c{c} }$} ();
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This `execute at begin node` setting will also be used unnecessarily by the two nodes used inside the wick diagram even though they don't contain any TikZ diagram and the setting is already set.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{simpler-wick}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[execute at begin node=\tikzset{-, shorten >=+0pt}]
\draw (0,0) to [scale=4, in=60, out=300, loop]
               node [right] {$\wick{ \c{a} \c{c} }$} ();
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]